# How to get current string of search bar while typing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

On pressing the searchbar I want to get the string that has already been entered. For that I am currently using this method:

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range     replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog(@"String:%@",mainSearchBar.text);
    return YES;
}
```

But it is returning the previous string. For example id i type "jumbo", it shows jumb and when i press backspace to delete one item and make it "jumb", it shows jumbo. i.e the previous string on the searchbar.

What should I do to get the current string? plsease help. 
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use `-searchBar:textDidChange:`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Inside the method you get the entered text with:

```
NSString* newText = [searchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text]
```

**Swift 3:**

```
let newText = (searchBar.text ?? "" as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)
```

Answer (score 5):

The most convenient delegate method to retrieve the new text from is:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

Both `[searchBar text]` and `searchText` will return the newly typed text.  `shouldChangeTextInRange` intentionally reports the old text because it permits you to cancel the edit before it happens.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
 - (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
    {
        NSString *str = [mainSearchBar.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text];
        NSLog(@"String:%@",str);
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        let newString = NSString(string: searchBar.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: text)

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String){
    print("searchText: \(searchText)")
}
```

This will fire whenever the text changes in the searchbar.